# How to plot different coloured GPS points (latitude and longitude) on a map for different categories of a key parameter using geom_point() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Overview:**

I am undertaking a study regarding how latitude influences leaf senescence (leaf loss) in deciduous oak trees *Q. Robur*.

I am completely new to producing maps in R and I have been trying to produce the desired results for a couple of days without success.

If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

**Problems:**

I produced a map of the UK using **my_map()** (see diagram 1) and I have a data frame called **lonlat_df** containing the longitude and latitude coordinates for all oak trees recorded.

I am trying to incorporate the tree data points onto the map of the UK using **geom_point()**. However, I am unsure how to integrate the map, the GPS points for the tree species, and the key parameter objects together.

**My goal**

To produce 3 separate maps of the UK showing the GPS points (see desired output below) for each oak tree species recorded in the study, but I would like the points to be 4 different colours to correlate with each key parameter category (see below), in conjunction with a legend for each parameter category.

**Key Parameters:**

1. **Urbanisation Index:** 1=Urban, 2=Suburban, 3=village, 4=rural
2. **Stand Density Index:** 1=standing alone, 2=within a few trees or close proximity to other trees, 3=within a stand of 10-30 trees, and 4=large or woodland
3. **Phenological Index:** 1=no indication of autumn timing, 2=first autumn tinting, 3=partial autumn tinting (>25% of leaves), and 4=advanced autumn tinting (>75% of leaves)

**R-code**

```
    ##Import Packages
    library(ggplot2)
    library(maps)
    library(mapdata)
    library(tidyverse)

    ##Create objects for the key parameters from the data frame below called QuercusRobur1 to use as point data

    latitude<-QuercusRobur1$Latitude
    longitude<-QuercusRobur1$Longitude
    PhenologyIndex<-QuercusRobur1$Phenological_Index
    StandDensityIndex<-QuercusRobur1$Stand_density_index
    UrbanisationIndex<-QuercusRobur1$Urbanisation_index
    Species<-QuercusRobur1$Species

   ##Produce new data frame

   lonlat_df<-as.data.frame(cbind(longitude, latitude, PhenologyIndex))
      head(lonlat_df)

  ##Produce a map of the UK from maps:
        UK <- map_data(map = "world", region = "UK")
        head(UK)
        dim(UK)

  ##Visualise the map of the UK using ggplot()
        dev.new()

        UK.Map<-ggplot(data = UK, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
                       geom_point(colour="red", size=3, alpha=0.2)+
                       geom_polygon() +
                       coord_map()

##Produce Point Data
        MapPoints<- MapUK + geom_point(data=lonlat_df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=PhenologyIndex), colour="red", shape=21, fill="red", size=0.5)
```

**Diagram 1**

[image]

**Desired output:**

I would like to overlay the type of points shown in the desired output below on the map of the UK produced from the R-code above.

[image]

**Dataframe**

```
   structure(list(Obs_.no = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
    35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 
    61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 
    75L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 93L, 
    102L, 103L, 104L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
    120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
    131L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
    149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
    162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
    180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 
    191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 
    205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 210L, 212L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
    219L, 220L, 221L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 237L, 239L, 246L, 255L, 256L, 
    257L, 258L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 277L, 278L, 
    279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 
    290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L), Date_observed = structure(c(4L, 
    15L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("10/1/18", 
    "10/19/18", "10/20/18", "10/21/18", "10/22/18", "10/23/18", "10/24/18", 
    "10/25/18", "10/26/18", "10/27/18", "10/28/18", "10/28/19", "10/29/18", 
    "12/9/18", "8/20/18"), class = "factor"), Latitude = c(51.4175, 
    52.12087, 52.0269, 52.0269, 52.0269, 52.0269, 52.947709, 52.947709, 
    51.491811, 51.491811, 52.59925, 52.59925, 52.59925, 52.59925, 
    51.60157, 51.60157, 52.6888, 52.6888, 52.6888, 52.6888, 50.697802, 
    50.697802, 50.697802, 50.697802, 53.62417, 50.446841, 50.446841, 
    53.959679, 53.959679, 53.959679, 53.959679, 51.78375, 51.78375, 
    51.78375, 51.78375, 51.456965, 51.456965, 51.456965, 51.456965, 
    51.3651, 51.3651, 51.3651, 51.3651, 52.01182, 52.01182, 52.01182, 
    52.01182, 50.114277, 50.114277, 51.43474, 51.43474, 51.10676, 
    51.10676, 51.10676, 51.10676, 50.435984, 50.435984, 50.435984, 
    50.435984, 51.78666, 51.78666, 52.441088, 52.441088, 52.552344, 
    49.259471, 49.259471, 49.259471, 49.259471, 50.461625, 50.461625, 
    50.461625, 50.461625, 51.746642, 51.746642, 51.746642, 51.746642, 
    52.2501, 52.2501, 52.2501, 52.2501, 52.423336, 52.423336, 52.423336, 
    52.423336, 53.615575, 53.615575, 53.615575, 53.615575, 51.08474, 
    51.08474, 51.08474, 53.19329, 53.19329, 53.19329, 53.19329, 55.96785, 
    55.96785, 56.52664, 56.52664, 56.52664, 56.52664, 51.8113, 51.8113, 
    51.8113, 51.8113, 52.580157, 52.580157, 52.580157, 52.580157, 
    50.52008, 50.52008, 50.52008, 50.52008, 51.48417, 51.48417, 51.48417, 
    51.48417, 54.58243, 54.58243, 54.58243, 54.58243, 52.58839, 52.58839, 
    52.58839, 52.58839, 52.717283, 52.717283, 52.717283, 52.717283, 
    50.740764, 50.740764, 50.740764, 50.740764, 52.57937, 52.57937, 
    52.57937, 52.57937, 50.736531, 50.736531, 50.79926, 50.79926, 
    50.79926, 53.675996, 53.675996, 48.35079, 48.35079, 48.35079, 
    48.35079, 51.36445, 51.36445, 51.36445, 51.36445, 52.122402, 
    52.122402, 52.122402, 52.16104, 52.16104, 55.91913, 51.6528, 
    51.6528, 51.6528, 51.6528, 51.88485, 51.88485, 51.88485, 51.88485, 
    52.34015, 52.34015, 52.34015, 52.026042, 52.026042, 52.026042, 
    52.026042, 51.319032, 51.319032, 51.319032, 51.319032, 51.51357, 
    51.51357, 51.51357, 51.51357, 53.43202, 53.43202, 53.43202, 53.43202, 
    51.50823, 51.50823, 51.50823, 51.50823), Longitude = c(-0.32118, 
    -0.29293, -0.7078, -0.7078, -0.7078, -0.7078, -1.435407, -1.435407, 
    -3.210324, -3.210324, 1.33011, 1.33011, 1.33011, 1.33011, -3.67111, 
    -3.67111, -3.30909, -3.30909, -3.30909, -3.30909, -2.11692, -2.11692, 
    -2.11692, -2.11692, -2.43155, -3.706923, -3.706923, -1.061008, 
    -1.061008, -1.061008, -1.061008, -0.65046, -0.65046, -0.65046, 
    -0.65046, -2.624917, -2.624917, -2.624917, -2.624917, 0.70706, 
    0.70706, 0.70706, 0.70706, -0.70082, -0.70082, -0.70082, -0.70082, 
    -5.541128, -5.541128, 0.45981, 0.45981, -2.32071, -2.32071, -2.32071, 
    -2.32071, -4.105617, -4.105617, -4.105617, -4.105617, -0.71433, 
    -0.71433, -0.176158, -0.176158, -1.337177, -123.107788, -123.107788, 
    -123.107788, -123.107788, 3.560973, 3.560973, 3.560973, 3.560973, 
    0.486416, 0.486416, 0.486416, 0.486416, -0.8825, -0.8825, -0.8825, 
    -0.8825, -1.787563, -1.787563, -1.787563, -1.787563, -2.432959, 
    -2.432959, -2.432959, -2.432959, -0.73645, -0.73645, -0.73645, 
    -0.63793, -0.63793, -0.63793, -0.63793, -3.18084, -3.18084, -3.40313, 
    -3.40313, -3.40313, -3.40313, -0.22894, -0.22894, -0.22894, -0.22894, 
    -1.948571, -1.948571, -1.948571, -1.948571, -4.20756, -4.20756, 
    -4.20756, -4.20756, -0.34854, -0.34854, -0.34854, -0.34854, -5.93229, 
    -5.93229, -5.93229, -5.93229, -1.96843, -1.96843, -1.96843, -1.96843, 
    -2.410575, -2.410575, -2.410575, -2.410575, -2.361234, -2.361234, 
    -2.361234, -2.361234, -1.89325, -1.89325, -1.89325, -1.89325, 
    -2.011143, -2.011143, -3.19446, -3.19446, -3.19446, -1.272824, 
    -1.272824, 10.91812, 10.91812, 10.91812, 10.91812, -0.23106, 
    -0.23106, -0.23106, -0.23106, -0.487443, -0.487443, -0.487443, 
    0.18702, 0.18702, -3.20987, -1.57361, -1.57361, -1.57361, -1.57361, 
    -0.17844, -0.17844, -0.17844, -0.17844, -1.27795, -1.27795, -1.27795, 
    -0.503114, -0.503114, -0.503114, -0.503114, -0.472994, -0.472994, 
    -0.472994, -0.472994, -3.18738, -3.18738, -3.18738, -3.18738, 
    -2.27968, -2.27968, -2.27968, -2.27968, -0.25847, -0.25847, -0.25847, 
    -0.25847), Altitude = c(5L, 0L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 104L, 104L, 
    15L, 15L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 184L, 184L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 176L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 178L, 36L, 36L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 210L, 
    210L, 210L, 210L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 160L, 160L, 
    160L, 160L, 166L, 166L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 58L, 
    58L, 58L, 58L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 133L, 
    133L, 133L, 133L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 
    129L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 96L, 
    96L, 96L, 96L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 75L, 75L, 
    109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 112L, 112L, 
    112L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), Species = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Quercus robur", class = "factor"), 
        Tree_diameter = c(68.8, 10, 98.5, 97, 32.5, 45.1, 847, 817, 
        62, 71, 140, 111.4, 114.6, 167.1, 29, 40.1, 68, 45, 60, 54, 
        104, 122, 85, 71, 81, 39.8, 43.6, 20.1, 17.8, 15.6, 12.1, 
        81.8, 102.5, 75.5, 57.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 70, 36, 53, 
        44, 31.5, 27.1, 23.3, 22, 69.4, 37.3, 19.9, 14.6, 196, 122, 
        118, 180, 58.6, 54.1, 58, 61.5, 58.4, 61, 134, 64, 52.2, 
        170, 114, 127, 158, 147.4, 135.3, 122.9, 104.1, 263, 237, 
        322, 302, 175, 182, 141, 155, 89, 41, 70, 83, 141, 86.5, 
        82, 114.5, 129, 127, 143, 125, 92, 68, 90, 24.5, 20.1, 63.7, 
        39.8, 66.2, 112.4, 124.5, 94.1, 68.6, 74.4, 23.6, 27.7, 22.9, 
        25.2, 24.2, 54.7, 43, 33.1, 306, 274, 56, 60, 72.5, 128.5, 
        22, 16, 143, 103, 53, 130, 48.4, 69.8, 6.4, 18.6, 129.2, 
        41.7, 57.6, 14, 41.7, 30.2, 39.5, 24.2, 320, 352, 120.9, 
        108.3, 53.2, 274, 85, 52, 43, 38, 37, 219, 215, 216, 175, 
        85.9, 49.7, 97.1, 40.8, 62.4, 80.3, 43, 50.3, 28.7, 31.9, 
        181.5, 149.7, 122, 143.6, 148, 145, 99, 28, 32, 54, 54, 169, 
        152, 160, 138, 90.8, 87.9, 77.4, 81.2, 91.7, 62.7, 50, 72.9, 
        23.7, 58, 80.7, 73.7), Urbanisation_index = structure(c(2L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
        "4"), class = "factor"), Stand_density_index = structure(c(3L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
        4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
        "4"), class = "factor"), Canopy_Index = c(85L, 85L, 85L, 
        75L, 45L, 25L, 75L, 65L, 75L, 75L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
        65L, 85L, 65L, 95L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 75L, 65L, 85L, 85L, 
        75L, 75L, 85L, 65L, 95L, 85L, 95L, 95L, 75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 
        85L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 
        65L, 75L, 85L, 75L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 75L, 65L, 95L, 95L, 
        55L, 75L, 65L, 75L, 65L, 85L, 95L, 95L, 75L, 95L, 75L, 95L, 
        65L, 75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 65L, 95L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 
        65L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 95L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 45L, 55L, 35L, 35L, 
        25L, 25L, 95L, 85L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 75L, 65L, 75L, 85L, 
        65L, 45L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 65L, 75L, 45L, 35L, 75L, 95L, 
        95L, 85L, 75L, 65L, 85L, 95L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 95L, 65L, 65L, 
        45L, 65L, 85L, 35L, 95L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 75L, 65L, 65L, 
        65L, 65L, 55L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 95L, 85L, 75L, 75L, 85L, 65L, 
        45L, 75L, 75L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 65L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 85L, 65L, 
        75L, 75L, 75L, 65L, 75L, 35L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 25L, 45L, 
        45L, 35L, 85L, 95L, 85L, 95L), Phenological_Index = c(2L, 
        4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -189L
    ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's helpful if you can pare this down to just the essentials needed to solve the issue, i.e. a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but complete example. We can recreate the issue with just a few points, and just the data needed to plot those points (lat, lon, group), and a lot less background information

Comment: Until then, have you tried adding a color argument inside your `aes` for the points? Just to map the group to the point color?

Comment: ggplot plots layers in the order listed, so right now you are plotting the map polygon OVER the points you want to see. Rearrange the order of your geoms so that `geom_polygon()` is before `geom_point()`, and you should see your points on top of the map.

Comment: Hey Jan, thank you for the suggestion. I changed the positions of the geoms but the map looks the same. The data contains 296 oak tree observations from all over the UK, so I feel that my R-code is wrong because many of those points will be on land rather than just outlining the whole of the UK and accompanying islands. Many thanks for your advice or any suggestions, it is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hi Camille, I re-edited the post to the minimum. I hope you find this post much improved. I have also updated my R-code. I am completely new to producing maps in R, and I really do feel confused with how to produce the desired result, which is for a deadline in two days. I have tried many different combinations of code in geom_point(). The main issue is I am unsure how to integrate the map I produced, the GPS points for the tree data, and the data for the key parameters together. If you are able to help me in any way, I would be deeply appreciative. Many thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create an additional data frame, especially if you don't include the key parameter variables there.

You can try this:

```
p <- ggplot(QuercusRobur1,
       aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) +
  geom_polygon(data = UK,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
               inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-10, 5)) + #limits added as there are some points really far away
  theme_classic()

p + 
  aes(color = Urbanisation_index) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Urbanisation Index",
                       labels = c("Urban", "Suburban", "Village", "Rural"))

p + 
  aes(color = Stand_density_index) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Stand Density Index",
                       labels = c("Standing alone",
                                  "Within a few trees or close proximity to other trees", 
                                  "Within a stand of 10-30 trees",
                                  "Large or woodland"))

p + 
  aes(color = factor(Phenological_Index)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Phenological Index",
                       labels = c("No indication of autumn timing", 
                                  "First autumn tinting", 
                                  "Partial autumn tinting (>25% of leaves)", 
                                  "Advanced autumn tinting (>75% of leaves)"))
```

[image: plot 1]

[image: plot 2]

[image: plot 3]

Comment: Hi Z.Lin, Thank you so much for your help! Now, I can see exactly what I was doing wrong. This has been an amazing learning experience. One question: one of the tree points GPS points is locatd in the sea. Is there any way I could locate what observation in my dataframe to omit it? Thank you, thank you.

Comment: @AliceHobbs Glad it helps. :) Since you can see (roughly) where the point is located, one quick way to remove weird points is to filter out the weird range. E.g. `QuercusRobur1 <- QuercusRobur1 %>% filter(Longitude <= 3)` (or some value like that).

Comment: Hey Z.Lin, it worked. You have been so amazing! Thank you again and enjoy your day :)